# Receiving the error "TypeError: callback is not a function"

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js and I am having a problem with my useForm.js, receiving the error "TypeError: callback is not a function." Here is the code I was testing from a youtube tutorial:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: ''
    });

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = e => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        });
    };
 
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setErrors(validate(values));
        setIsSubmitting(true);
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
            callback();
        }
    }, [errors]
    );

    return {handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors};
};

export default useForm;
```

I'm calling my hook through my CreateAccount page which contains the form. I am trying to pull up the CreateAccountSuccess page once the user successfully enters the correct info and presses the submit button. (I have a separate file which does all the validating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling your hook? You need to provide `callback` and `validate` props.
Something like this:

```
const callback = () => console.log('I am callback');
const validate = () => console.log('I am validation');

const {handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors} = useForm(callback, validate);
```

You could also add confirmation that `callback` and `validation` exist.

```
useEffect(
        () => {
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
          if (callback) {
            callback()
          }
        }
    }, [errors]
    );

const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (validate){
          setErrors(validate(values));
        }
        setIsSubmitting(true);
    };
```

Comment: I'm calling my hook through my CreateAccount page which contains the form. I am trying to pull up the CreateAccountSuccess page once the user successfully enters the correct info and presses the submit button. (I have a separate file which does all the validating)

Your above code, helped and got rid of the error thank you! But now when I press submit nothing happens. Probably have to look over my code again. 

Thanks again!